# How to select all unused bones?

Tags: armature

Good day. I have armature and hair mesh. But armature contains a lot of unused bones (I mean without any weight paint). How can I select and delete all these bones?

[image]

[image]

Comment: google is your friend: https://github.com/aoirusann/BlenderAddon_RemoveUnuseVertexGroupsAndBones i did not try that but i looks like exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @Chris well, I've tried it, and can't even install it. Description says: "Install as a blender addon.". But after installation I don't see this addon in addons menu. I've tried it with Blender 3.6 and 4.0.